# I can not install a new MAC OS wallet bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, mac

I launch the wallet, the block index starts loading, then blocks are rewound, then 1% and after the wallet crashes, what should I do ?

Comment: Hello Andrey, could you tell us which version of Bitcoin-Qt and Mac OS you're using?

Comment: 10.13.6 Mac os, Bitcoin Core 0.19.0.1